# What permissions do I need to open site & workflows in SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions

I'm trying to view/edit a workflow in SharePoint 2007, but keep getting denied access.

In `SharePoint Designer`, I click `open site`, then I put in the URL of the site.  Only a portion of the site loads, and more specifically, not the workflows I am looking for do.  Additionally, I thought there should be an `open workflow` option on the `file` drop-down menu, which I do not see.

What permissions does my user need to have to see the file site?

Comment: Did you try with Full Control permission on the site? Did you check the SharePoint Designer general setting on the web application from the Site Admin Console?

Answer (score 0):

Your user will need designer level permissions. I'm not sure how the groups are setup by default in SharePoint 2007 though.

Comment: I have full access under the Designer user group.  Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows in SharePoint 2007 require you to have full control permissions.

Designer is not enough for you to save the workflow.

Here's a link to a similar question with more detail.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301820/minimum-permission-required-to-publish-a-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer

Answer (score 0):

You need to have site collection administrator permission to perform this action.